Eyebrow Segmentation with Mediapipe in Python
I'm currently working on a project that involves eyebrow segmentation using the Mediapipe library in Python. Despite my efforts in researching and experimenting with the available resources, I'm encountering difficulties in implementing this feature effectively.
Would anyone be able to provide guidance or share code snippets for achieving eyebrow segmentation with Mediapipe? I've explored the documentation and various online tutorials, but I'm struggling to adapt the concepts to my project's requirements.
If anyone has experience or insights into implementing eyebrow segmentation specifically with Mediapipe, I would greatly appreciate any assistance or pointers you could offer.
Thank you very much for your time and consideration!
jpuioiu
